# I keep getting an "else without if" error

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm trying to write some code that makes the user input a valid username and they get three tries to do it. Every time I compile it I get an **else without if** error wherever I have a else if statement.

```
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

  String validName = "thomsondw";

  System.out.print("Please enter a valid username: ");
  String input1 = in.next();

  if (input1.equals(validName))
  {
    System.out.println("Ok you made it through username check");
  }
  else
  {
    String input2 = in.next(); 
  }
  else if (input2.equals(validName))
  {
    System.out.println("Ok you made it through username check");
  }
  else
  {
    String input3 = in.next();
  }
  else if (input3.equals(validName))
  {
    System.out.println("Ok you made it through username check");
  }
  else
  {
    return;
  }
```

Comment: `if(condition){ }else{ }else{ }` doesn't seem right. First `else` handles situation where condition was false, but what second `else` should handle?

Answer (score 9):

You are misunderstanding the use of `if-else`

```
if(condition){
  //condition is true here
}else{
  //otherwise
}else if{
  // error cause it could never be reach this condition
}
```

Read more [The if-then and if-then-else Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html)

You can have

```
if(condition){

}else if (anotherCondition){

}else{
  //otherwise means  'condition' is false and 'anotherCondition' is false too
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have an `if` followed by an `else`, that ends the block. You can have `if` followed by multiple `else if` statements, but only one `else` -- and the `else` must be last.

Comment: How would you say a string is not equal to another string

Comment: Sounds like you want the "not" operator: !. For example, `if (! string1.equals(string2)) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

You need to either: change all your "else" except the last to "else if", or put plain "if" before the following "else if" statements:

(1)

```
else if (input2.equals(validName))
{
    System.out.println("Ok you made it through username check");
}
```

(2)

```
else if (input3.equals(validName))
{
    System.out.println("Ok you made it through username check");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not very maintainable. What would you do, if the user got 5 tries? Add some additional if blocks? And what if the user has 10 tries? :-) You see what I mean.

Try the following instead:

```
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int tries = 0;
    int maxTries = 3;
    String validName = "thomsondw"; 
    while (tries < maxTries) {
        tries++;
        System.out.print("Please enter a valid username: ");
        String input = in.next();
        if (input.equals(validName)) {
            System.out.println("Ok you made it through username check");
            break; //leaves the while block
        } 
    }
```